# Solve differentional equation in $S'$

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve differentional equation in $ S' $.

$F^{'}(x) - F(x) = e^{2x}$.

I know that solution in $D^{'}$ :$ F(x)=Ce^{x} + e^{2x} $, where $C$ is any constant.
But I don't know how to get solution in the space $S'$.
Would be very glad for any help!

Comment: Why do you think that the same function will not be a solution in $S'$?

Comment: I don't know, how to prove it.

Comment: It's obvious that $\int(F'(x)-F(x)-e^{2x})\varphi(x)dx=0$, where $\varphi\in S$. So, by theory, $F'(x)-F(x)-e^{2x}=0$ almost everywhere.

Comment: It's wrong, because $e^{2x}$ isn't in S'

Comment: I don't say anything about $e^{2x}$.

Comment: At least I see only one interpretation of your equation in the sense of generalized functions in $S'$.